# Is there a way to save the Locust Charts as image files in both Web/NoWeb methods?

Tags: locust

I would like to know if there is a way to save the Locust Charts generated in the Web Interface as image files (jpg/png) formats. If yes, could you please show me how?

Is it possible to save the charts as images from no-web execution method?

Thank you. Please consider this as a feature request or recommend if there are any alternatives I can consider.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the download link at the top right corner of the graph (hover it with your mouse)

[image]

It is currently not possible to do in no-web mode.

For more advanced graphing solutions (that also work in no-web) you might consider locust-plugins's Timescale+Graphana solution (built by me :) https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/timescale_listener.py / https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10878